# System date on laptop resume set in the future

Tags: 22.04, suspend, time, date

I have an HP 15-EF2XXXX series laptop with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS installed. The laptop works great in all regards, considering the cheap build quality.

However, at the end of the day I suspend the OS by closing the laptop lid and once or twice a week (this seems to happen randomly), when I resume the OS and log back in, the system clock is always set about 100 years in the future to a random day and month.

Today when I opened it up, it was set to Jan 14 2134. When this happens, I have to open the Gnome Settings panel, scroll down to date and time, and uncheck "Automatically Date & Time" and re-check it.

I also tried just manually setting the system clock, thinking it might be an issue with NTP, but, like clockwork, a few days later the same thing happened again without Automatic Date & Time being set.

I've tried searching for this about 10 different times across DDG and Google, looking for everything from "Linux time set to the future on suspend/resume" to "Ubuntu Automatic Date Time incorrect Laptop". Normally I'm able to find something in one of the search engines, but this is one of the only times I've ever been completely stymied. At this point, I don't even know what I should be looking for in the system that could be causing this behavior.

Anybody have any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There could be a problem with your computer's internal real time clock rather than due to automatic synchronization. Try to replace your CMOS battery. Also check if its connector or wire seems to be damaged.

Comment: Are there any programs or files I can check that would let me test this? I'm more of a software guy than hardware, and what little comfort I have with hardware does not extend to laptop internals. :D